# How to approach Java testing manner structure

Tags: java, testing

I use TestNG framework, but I will provide my problem without that framework so everyone can understand.

Let's say I have BaseClass that inits WebDriver and has it as public var.
My TestClass must extend BaseClass (As it is a must in TestNG framework)
But for easier development I want external class TestFunctionsClass so it holds functionality of tests. Also my TestFunctionsClass extends ElementActions class that has it's specific elements.

So current approach is to initialize TestFunctionsClass inside TestClass and push WebDriver through parameters, and inside TestFunctionsClass use super instance to give WebDriver to a parent class (ElementActions).

So the problem is if my BaseClass would contain many inits like Logger, Driver, etc... It would be a mess to keep everything pushing through parameters to instances. So is there a better appraoch to this?

Here's code example, and if there could be a better approach to reduce code without instances in each parent classes from TestFunctions class:

```
public Class Base {
  WebDriver driver;

  // beforeTest
  void public setUp() {
      driver = init...
  }
}

public Class Test extends Base {
  public void runTest() {
      TestFunctions testFunctions = new TestFunctions(driver);
  }
}

public Class TestFunctions extends Actions {
  WebDriver driver;

  public TestFunctions(WebDriver driver) {
      super(driver);
    
      this.driver = driver;
  }
}


public Class Actions {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Actions(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public click() {
        // driver accessable here
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "I want external class TestFunctionsClass so it holds functionality of tests."? What kind of functionality? I'm not familiar with TestNG, but the [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/index.html) suggests you don't need to extend another class.

Comment: Further, your example isn't valid Java code. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the problem, as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.